# How do I show FPS in Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I enable the FPS readout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Dwarf Fortress wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Maximizing_framerate):

> Framerate  is used in Dwarf Fortress to measure the speed at which the game is running. To check your FPS (frames per second) in Dwarf Fortress, simply change [FPS:NO] to [FPS:YES] in init.txt, and your FPS will be displayed near the top right corner of the screen.